Does AWS API Gateway allow colons within the query string of a request for HTTP APIs?
I have an API which accepts start and end query string parameters, which are expected to be ISO 8601 datetime strings (e.g. YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ). Those strings contain colons (:).
I'm fronting this API with AWS API Gateway (specifically, an API Gateway HTTP API). When I make a request to my route and include the start or end query string parameters, with values that include colons, API Gateway appears to fall back to my $default route. If I URL-encode the colons (%3A), things work correctly.
As I read RFC 3986, the query string is defined as:
query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )

... with pchar further defined as:
   pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"

... which suggests to me that by the RFC, un-escaped colons should be allowed within the query string.
Un-escaped colons in query strings seem to work fine for other popular APIs, including GitHub's issues API, which also exposes a datetime filtering query string parameter.
I have not been able to find any AWS documentation which explicitly notes this limitation. The important notes page is perhaps closest, but it says nothing about disallowed characters in query strings for HTTP APIs. It does mention some restrictions on query string characters for REST APIs, but colon is not specifically mentioned. It says:


The plain text pipe character (|) and the curly brace character ({ or }) are not supported for any request URL query string and must be URL-encoded.
The semicolon character (;) is not supported for any request URL query string and results in the data being split.
REST APIs decode URL-encoded request parameters before passing them to backend integrations. For UTF-8 request parameters, REST APIs decode the parameters and then pass them as unicode to backend integrations. REST APIs URL-encode the percent character (%) before passing it to backend integrations.


So: is the inability to include non-URL-encoded colons in the query string an intentional limitation of AWS API Gateway? Is it documented somewhere?

Wow, and this definitely looks like a bug - (valid) query parameters shouldn't affect path matching. If you have a support plan, it's the right time to use it, otherwise consider asking on AWS re:post - sometimes bugs reported there are heard and fixed.

@jwilner these are exactly the questions SO is here for, ChatGPT will just make up nonsense to tell you it is supported, then you question it further and it will confirm that it had not clue what it was talking about and you are back at square one (or the other way around depending on how you phrased the prompt). Case in point I just did that and it first told me colon is not url safe, questioned it further and it confirmed that it is safe quoting the RFC, thanks for nothing.
